# How to use distribution certificates in a team of two developers

Tags: ios, build, certificate, provisioning

I have created an application for a client and been building it on my laptop using a distribution certificate.

There is now a new member on the team.  Am I correct to think that we have to share the same distribution certificate in order to create builds of the app?  Or can we each have our own distribution certificate?

If we have to share the same one, do I simply "export" the team provisioning from my XCode Organiser?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Export it with a password, and you can give the resulting file to your colleague.